# Error when decoding a gif using giflib

Tags: c++, giflib

I'm attempting to decode .gif files using giflib. The following code leads to a segfault on the final line (the output width/height is correct).

```
GifFileType* gif = DGifOpenFileName(filename.c_str(), &errCode);
if (gif == NULL) {
    std::cout << "Failed to open .gif, return error with type " << errCode << std::endl;
    return false;
}

int slurpReturn = DGifSlurp(gif);
if (slurpReturn != GIF_OK) {
    std::cout << "Failed to read .gif file" << std::endl;
    return false;
}

std::cout << "Opened .gif with width/height = " << gif->SWidth << " " << gif->SHeight << std::endl;
std::cout <<  gif->SavedImages[0].RasterBits[0] << std::endl;
```

Output:

```
 Opened .gif with width/height = 921 922
 zsh: segmentation fault (core dumped)  ./bin/testgiflib
```

As I understand, giflib should populate gif->SavedImages. But it is NULL after calling DGifSlurp().

Any ideas would be appreciated.

**EDIT**

I've added the following lines of code following a suggestion in comments:

```
if (gif->SavedImages == NULL) {
    std::cout <<"SavedImages is NULL" << std::endl;
}
```

The line is printed, indicating that SavedImages is NULL.

**EDIT2**

Some gifs on which this issue occurs (note that I can't get it to work on any gifs):

https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/3/39/Specialist_Science_Logo.gif

```
 GIF image data, version 89a, 921 x 922
```

https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/25/Nasa-logo.gif

```
 GIF image data, version 87a, 1008 x 863
```

Comment: Can you somehow check if the GIF may be malformed?

Comment: Thanks for your input. I've tested with multiple gifs, including some from the internet + some that come with giflib, so I don't think that's the issue here.

Comment: having lots of .'s and ->'s in the same statement can confuse matters. Could you try examining the validity of gif->SavedImages[0], then only if that is valid, dereferencing RasterBits[0]?

Comment: Thanks Jimmy, please see my edit.

Comment: Can you post a link to an online GIF on which this code fails? (I don't think you can use the standard "upload-your-image", I think it translates everything to PNG!)

Comment: I've added some link to gifs in my post.

Comment: Your code seems fine. [Have you tried version 4](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16893150/865719) ?

Comment: Let me look into that. This seems like a rather significant bug for such an old codebase though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Preface: Looks like in my version of giflib, 4.1.6, the `DGifOpenFileName()` function takes only the filename parameter, and does not return an error code, which is an irrelevant detail.

After adjusting for the API change, and adding the necessary includes, I compiled and executed the following complete, standalone test program:

```
#include <gif_lib.h>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    GifFileType* gif = DGifOpenFileName("Specialist_Science_Logo.gif");

    if (gif == NULL) {
        std::cout << "Failed to open .gif, return error with type " << std::endl;
        return false;
    }

    int slurpReturn = DGifSlurp(gif);
    if (slurpReturn != GIF_OK) {
        std::cout << "Failed to read .gif file" << std::endl;
        return false;
    }

    std::cout << "Opened .gif with width/height = " << gif->SWidth << " " << gif->SHeight << std::endl;
    std::cout <<  (int)gif->SavedImages[0].RasterBits[0] << std::endl;
}
```

Except for the presence of the header files, the slightly different `DGifOpenFilename()` signature, and my tweak to cast the second output line's value to an explicit `(int)`, this is identical to your code. Also, the code was changed to explicitly open the `Specialist_Science_Logo.gif` file, one of the GIF image files you were having an issue with.

This code executed successfully on Fedora x86-64, giflib 4.1.6, gcc 5.5.1, without any issues.

Instrumenting the sample code with [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) did not reveal any memory access violations.

From this, I conclude that there is nothing wrong with the shown code. The shown code is obviously an excerpt from a larger application. The bug lies elsewhere in this application, or perhaps giflib itself, and only manifests here.

Comment: Thanks Sam. I'm rather confident that this is a bug in giflib now. Works for me in 4.1.1 but fails in 5.1.6. I've submitted a bug report to the giflib project: http://sourceforge.net/p/giflib/bugs/68/